# Is it possible to call a variable file inside another variable file in robot framework

Tags: python, robotframework

I am using variable files to parametrise my robot framework tests  in order to run my tests against a website having different languages.

Now I would like to use variable files in order to parametrise tests against different environments: PreProd, Test...

At the moment when I would like to run my tests against English version of my website I would run this command :

```
pybot -V EN.py tests.robot
```

This command will run all tests on EN website.

What I would like to do is to add a new variable file where I could change values inside my first variable file : EN.py in order to change the URL prefix.

EN.py

```
 home_url = "test-wwww.mywebsite.en"
```

I would like to have another variable file to change the home_url to :

envtest.py

```
env-test = test-
```

And finally use this variable in side my first variable file :

home_url = env_test + "wwww.mywebsite.en"

I am clear about hot to structure this but not sure on how to implement it, precisely how to call a variable in a variable file 1 in another variable in a second variable file 2.

basically I would need to have a python cross modules variable.

Hope I was clear enough.

Thanks